# How to return \count value from \def

Tags: macros, tex-core, texdef

I wrote a macro which calculate remainder :

```
\def\remainder#1#2 {%
    \newcount\dividendcount
    \dividendcount=#1
    \newcount\quotientcount
    \quotientcount=#1
    \divide\quotientcount #2
    \multiply\quotientcount #2
    \advance\dividendcount -\quotientcount
    \number\dividendcount
}
```

I want use value from \remainder in other macro. For instance,

```
\def\othermacro#1 {%
    \newcount\tempcount
    \tempcount=#1
    \divide\tempcount 2
    #1 / 2 = \number\tempcount
}
```

I want write something similar

```
\begin{document}
    \othermacro{\remainder{17}{3}}
\end{document}
```

And to give next results

```
2 / 2 = 1
```

How can I do it?

Comment: The `calculator` package provides a lot of `\def` - like macros, containing the result of a computation, the `\MODULO` macro is also available

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few errors in the definition of `\remainder` and `\othermacro`: a `\newcount` declaration mustn't go inside them, because this would waste a counter at each call. Also a space after `#2` is significant and it means that TeX looks for a space after the second argument, raising an error if it doesn't find one and taking as second argument everything that follows the first argument up to this space.

```
\newcount\dividendcount
\newcount\quotientcount
\def\remainder#1#2{%
  \dividendcount=#1
  \quotientcount=#1
  \divide\quotientcount #2
  \multiply\quotientcount #2
  \advance\dividendcount -\quotientcount
  \number\dividendcount
}
```

would be more correct. However this is the instruction for *printing* the remainder and it's not legal in an assignment like

```
\tmpcount=\remainder{17}{3}
```

because TeX wants a `<number>` after the `=`, not the instructions to produce one.

If you plan to use `\remainder` in the context of an assignment like that, you need to make it expandable and this needs `\numexpr`.

It's quite easy with `expl3`; I'll assume LaTeX, but it can be done also with Plain TeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\remainder}{mm}
 {
  \int_eval:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\othermacro}{m}
 {
  $ % enter math mode
  #1/2=\int_eval:n { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { 2 } }
  $ % exit math mode
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\othermacro{\remainder{17}{3}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the Plain TeX version

```
\input expl3-generic.tex

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \remainder #1 #2
 {
  \int_eval:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \othermacro #1
 {
  $ % enter math mode
  #1/2=\int_eval:n { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { 2 } }
  $ % exit math mode
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\othermacro{\remainder{17}{3}}

\bye
```

Without `expl3`:

```
\def\truncdiv#1#2{((#1-(#2-1)/2)/#2)}
\def\remainder#1#2{#1-\truncdiv{#1}{#2}*#2}
\def\eval#1{\number\numexpr#1\relax}

\def\othermacro#1{$\eval{#1}/2=\eval{\truncdiv{#1}{2}}$}

\othermacro{\remainder{17}{3}}

\bye
```